# How can I click on an item in windows Start Menu using AutoIt?

Tags: treeview, autoit, startmenu

I am able to open then Start Menu and I am able to expand the nodes and child nodes in the Start Menu.  Now, how can I perform the action of clicking on an item so that it will launch the corresponding application.

Regards, 
Nazir

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
Send("^{ESC}")  ;[CTRL][ESC] to open the start menu
WinWaitActive("Start menu","")
ControlClick("Start menu","","[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]") ;click on 'All Programs'
$hTree = ControlGetHandle("Start menu", "", "[CLASS:SysTreeView32; INSTANCE:1]") ; get handle to the treeview window
ControlTreeView("Start menu","",$hTree,"Expand", "#0|#13") ; expand a node
ControlTreeView("Start menu","",$hTree,"Expand", "#0|#13|#10") ; expand a child node of the above node
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you want to select forth item do this.

```
Send("{DOWN 3}")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Or you can use ControlSend() if you wanna make sure you are hitting the right window.